# Creating and reading a one time created file

Tags: java, android

I want to store a list of strings in a file.

I need to create it just one time, and after that i will read and write on it programmaticlly.

My question is where in the file system should i create the file (manually) so that it will best for reading and writing ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create your file in your app's directory so no one can access it but your app

```
getApplicationContext().getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath();
```

or on sd card

```
File externalStorage = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
```

if you want others to access it and, maybe, if your file is very big

If you intent to create your file *manually* then I think SD card is the only option unless you have a rooted phone or working with the emulator.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(Environment.getExternalStorageState())) 
    {
         //SDcard is there
         File f=new File("/sdcard/YOURFILE.txt");
         if (!f.exists())
         {
             //File created only for first time
             f.createNewFile();
           //create inputstream and write it to your file
           OutputStream out=new FileOutputStream(f);
           byte buf[]=new byte[1024];
           int len;
           while((len=inputStream.read(buf))>0)
           out.write(buf,0,len);
           out.close();
           inputStream.close();
           System.out.println("\nData Written");
         }
         else {  //  read/ write SECOND TIME  }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

It really depends.

The problem with creating the file on the SDCard is that a special permission is required in order to access it. If the app is only for yourself, that's cool. If you want to distribute it through Google <strike>Market</strike>Play (or whatever it is called these days), please know that some people (myself included) tend to look at the permissions and ask "why would an app doing X require permission to do Y?", and sometimes not install the app because of it.

If the manual part is done by the app's user, by all means, store it on the sdcard. It's the only place a standard, none-root user even has access to.

Generally speaking, however, a better place to store data is in /data/data/packagename. See Android's [data storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal) for more details.

Shachar

Answer (score -1):

Add file in assets folder, then it will be clearly after new install

Comment: If you will add file in assets folder it will be in all app's .apk as singelton